# Google Oauth recognizing G-Suite account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-workspace

I am trying to add Google Sign In to my application. I want to limit who can  sign in to a list of allowed companies (ie. a company that has a billing account with me). I intended to do this by limiting sign in to only G-Suite accounts. Is there any way to check if a user is trying to log in with a   G-Suite account and is there any way to uniquely identify who owns the G-Suite (some kind of corporate identifier inside google)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For G-Suite you can use the [Hosted Domain (hd) parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) within OpenID Connect.

Be sure to **heed the details** as this only manipulates the UI and does not ensure the Authorization request. The APP must code the verification.